# serialize array in hadoop

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce

I want to serialize a stringarray "textData"  and send it from mapper to reducer

```
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector< IntWritable,Text > 
                 output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

                  Path pt=new Path("E:\\spambase.txt");
                 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                BufferedReader textReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));


             int numberOfLines =  readLines( );
             String[ ] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
                 int i;
                 for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                 textData[ i ] = textReader.readLine();
                 }
                 textReader.close();
```

Comment: Please review your code formatting and say what already tried, did you search in older questions ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945769/in-a-mapreduce-how-to-send-arraylist-as-value-from-mapper-to-reducer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810550/output-a-list-from-a-hadoop-map-reduce-job-using-custom-writable

Comment: yes .i serached on older question ,but i cant find the answer.

Comment: I understood the best way for sending an array from mapper to reducer is serializing and i dont know how to do it.

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: The upper code id my mapper and the "textdata" is my array.I want to seialze it and send it to the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some misunderstanding about how the MapReduce process works.

The mapper should ideally not read an entire file within itself.

A Job object generates a collection of InputSplits for a given input path.
By default, Hadoop reads one line of each split in the path (the input can be a directory), or just of the given file.
Each line is passed *one at a time into* `Text value` of your map class at the `LongWritable key` *offset of the input*.

Its not clear what you are trying to output, but you're looking for the `ArrayWritable` class and you serialize data to a reducer using `output.collect()`. However you need to modify your mapper output types from `IntWritable, Text` to use `output.collect(some_key, new ArrayWritable(textData))`

It's worth pointing out that you're using the deprecated `mapred` libraries, not the `mapreduce` ones. And that `E:\\` is not an hdfs path, but a local filesystem.